# Bootstrap Navbar Align Right

Tags: html, css, django, navbar

I'm trying to align my navbar items to the right in bootstrap.

I'd like to have everything aligned right, except for the brand logo.

```
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" /></a></h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul>
      <li class="drop-down"><a href="#services"><span>Services</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Test1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Test11</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Test12</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Stats</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Stats1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stats2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Support</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstrap 5 here is an example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Watch the  tag. It has a class "ms-auto". This will align all links to the right. Using "me-auto" will align all elements to the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `margin-left: auto` to achieve right-align. Boostrap 4 has a default `ml-auto` class that has this style.

Assuming that you're existing example is working, try:

```html
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" /></a></h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul class="ml-auto">
      <li class="drop-down"><a href="#services"><span>Services</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Test1</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Test11</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Test12</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><span>Stats</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Stats1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stats2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Support</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```

In Bootstrap 5 you will simply replace `ml-auto` as `ms-auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
 <style>
    .logo { float: left; }
    .nav-menu { float: right; }
    .drop-down { float: left; }
 </style>
```